# Unable to play Youtube stream via VideoView. How do I fix this?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying to play a youtube video using VideoView. It gives me **"can not play video"** error. What am I doing wrong in the code below. The URL I am using is just regular youtube URL : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7u30Li-oOc

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //init components for use
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //Get URI data from VideoDemo activity
    Bundle uristream = getIntent().getExtras();
    videoUri = uristream.getString("urivalue"); 

    //set Texfield to URI string
    text.setText(videoUri);


     //mVideoView.setVideoPath(videoUri);

    //provide VideoView component with file path and play
     mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUri));
     mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
     mVideoView.requestFocus();
     mVideoView.start();

  }
```

Comment: can you post the full exception please?

Comment: It does not really give much of an exception. It says "Can not play. Sorry this video can not be played".  Tag: MediaPlayer error(0 , 0). I am running the the app on a logitech (Google TV)

Comment: @MahdeTo , it also says "Couldn't open file on client side try server side"

Comment: I have the exact problem. Have you found any solutions?

Comment: @Juhani, No unfortunately I haven't. I just found a work around for my app.

Answer (score 0):

no need to create separate video view we can play youtube videos directly by using this intent

```
startActivity(newIntent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("video url")));
```

Comment: What if I wanted to stream non youtube content. Videos stored on a Database somewhere etc. Would this be applicable?

Comment: How would I invoke the OS default player for any file?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your phone does not support MP4 videos. Try using video players like daroon which play all sort of videos. First test your application if you able to play videos with .3gp extension. If you cannot, then the problem is with your code.

```
      Uri video = Uri.parse(videoUri);

     videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoUri)));
     videoView.setVideoURI(video);
     videoView.setVideoPath(videoUri);
     videoView.requestFocus();
     videoView.start();
```

For more info, go through [android media format support](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: I am running the the app on a logitech (Google TV) not a phone.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same exact code above , but instead  of using a youtube url for the videoUri. I uploaded a video to my site database and set videouri to that URL. **IT WORKED!!** *Apparently VideoView and Youtube streams do not work well together.*

```
 mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUri));
 mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
 mVideoView.requestFocus();
 mVideoView.start();
```